# Potential bug in np.isnan() for mixed types on pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have run into a bug with np.isnan(). It may be that it is intended to work this way and the problem is how pandas handles it. If I make a dataframe with mixed types like

```
raw_data = {'Binary 1': [True, True, False, False, True], 
    'Binary 2': [False, False, True, True, False], 
    'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Binary 1', 'Binary 2', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

df.dtypes


Binary 1          bool
Binary 2          bool
age              int64
preTestScore     int64
postTestScore    int64
```

I can't call

```
np.isnan(df)
```

**TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''**

Both this

```
np.isnan(df[['Binary 1', 'Binary 2']])
```

and this

```
np.isnan(df[['age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore']])
```

work. I think it is because they are of the same type since this does not

```
np.isnan(df[['Binary 1', 'age']])
```

Comment: I don't think this is a bug but rather that numpy doesn't want to coerce multiple types of data to the same datatype, as you said.

Comment: Easy work around --> use print(pd.isnull(df[['Binary 1', 'age']])) and not numpy

Comment: [Also Related](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/432)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.isnan` is a `numpy` function, so it works with numpy arrays, and values derived from the input:

```
In [418]: df[['Binary 1', 'Binary 2']].values                                   
Out[418]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False]])
```

This is a 2d boolean dtype array.  But the whole dataframe has mixed dtypes, so it produces an object dtype:

```
In [419]: df.values                                                             
Out[419]: 
array([[True, False, 42, 4, 25],
       [True, False, 52, 24, 94],
       [False, True, 36, 31, 57],
       [False, True, 24, 2, 62],
       [True, False, 73, 3, 70]], dtype=object)
```

Casting that array to `int` (or float), runs ok: `np.isnan(df.values.astype(int))`

But as pointed out in the comments, `pandas` has its own `nan` tester, which I believe is even more powerful (and forgiving).  The `np.isnan` is really intended for float arrays, since `np.nan` is a float.