# Is the best way to test NaN and NaT in Numpy actually by using Pandas isnull()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Working with a small csv dataset that I imported using Pandas `read_csv()`, some of the values that were missing came out as `Numpy NaN` type and some of the missing datetimes came in as `Numpy NaT` type. The actual data types of those columns aren't those types but Pandas doesn't know that - it thinks they're those types.

To test for both of these cases it seems like the best method is actually to use Pandas' `isnull()` function - my question is why does Numpy not have this functionality built in? Am I missing something or is using Pandas the best way to test Numpy types? Numpy's builtin `isnan()` function doesn't seem to be the way to do it.

A bit more context:

I get this typing warning - `Module is not callable` - when type checking with Numpy's `isnan()`, and digging deeper the error it gave me is `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.` so it seems to be concerned that I'm passing in a different type.

To reproduce this: pass in a string to `np.isnan()` and it will throw the error. e.g. `np.isnan('test')` will throw that error.

Why isn't that the expected way to use this method?? To pass in different data types? Why is the default behavior to throw an error? And why is the seeming best way to handle checking for a Numpy data type by using Panda's `isnull()` if the datatype is actually a Numpy data type?

Thanks all

My code:

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from typing import Dict, Any
def a(my_obj:Dict[str, Any]):
    for key, value in my_obj.items():
        # this will throw an error if you pass in a string
        if np.isnan(value):
            my_obj[key] = None
        # this one gives no error and actually works
        if pd.isnull(value):
            my_obj[key] = None
    return my_obj
            
# this is true only if you comment out the `np.isnan()` lines
assert a({"working":"123", "typing_not_working":np.nan}) == {"working":"123", "typing_not_working":None}```
````

Comment: Please post your issue in a way that it is reproducible. Here you're showing us that the line of code `np.isnan(value)` produces an error. And you're hoping that we can tell you why. Well, we can't. Not unless you tell us what `value` is. Please post a few more lines of codes so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: That being said, does this similar post answer your question? [Potential bug in np.isnan() for mixed types on pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637976/potential-bug-in-np-isnan-for-mixed-types-on-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: sure, just added a much better example

Comment: that answer you provided doesn't mention `isnull()` by name but does refer to how it is better. in my example i'm passing in a single string and a single Numpy NaN.

Comment: Please don't post text as pictures. Please copy paste the code and add it as text in your post.

Comment: Added the text as code

Comment: On a tangential note: you might have noticed that the name of variable `input` shows up in a different colour than the names of other variables. That's because `input` is already the name of a builtin function in python. Shafowing the names of builtins is confusing for people who read your code, but also it can have unintended consequences when running the code; it is strongly discouraged.

Comment: I just tried running your code. It worked fine. There was no error. `a({"working":"123", "typing_not_working":np.nan})` evaluates to `{'working': '123', 'typing_not_working': None}` as expected. I don't know why you got the "module not callable" error; I didn't.

Comment: Hi i believe i've addressed both those issues just now.

Answer (score 0):

- **np.nan >>> 'float dtype'**
- This np.isnan  do not work on 'string type'
  and which test-element-wise

Please do check this:
[TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657223/typeerror-ufunc-isnan-not-supported-for-the-input-types-and-the-inputs-could)